# Microsoft DLP Policy Disclaimer Exclusion

Tags: xml

I created a DLP Custom Rule Pack to identify the below keywords by the DLP Policy.

Internal Use
Confidential
Client Confidential
Restricted

I want to exclude my organization disclaimer in the custom DLP Policy for that purpose I have created the below code but it is not working fine.

```
  <Any  maxMatches="0" minMatches="0">
    <Match idRef="Organization_Disclaimer"/>
  </Any>
```

I have the data classification that contains the word Confidential I want to trigger the DLP Policy when it matches the data classification.

But we have an organization disclaimer so I want to exclude that, otherwise, all the emails will detect by the DLP Policy they may result in a false positive.

So please help me to achieve my goal.

Thanks in Advance.